# Test set accuracy of 1. How to debug

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning, neural-network

I am trying to create a simple neural network using tensorflow as a learning exercise. These are the details of the NN I created..

```
def multilayer_perceptron(x, weights, biases, keep_prob):
    layer_1 = tf.add(tf.matmul(x, weights['h1']), biases['b1'])
    layer_1 = tf.nn.relu(layer_1)
    layer_1 = tf.nn.dropout(layer_1, keep_prob)
    out_layer = tf.matmul(layer_1, weights['out']) + biases['out']
    return out_layer

n_hidden_1 = 38
n_input = train_x.shape[1]
n_classes = train_y.shape[1]

weights = {
    'h1': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_input, n_hidden_1])),
    'out': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_hidden_1, n_classes]))
}

biases = {
    'b1': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_hidden_1])),
    'out': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_classes]))
}

keep_prob = tf.placeholder("float")

training_epochs = 500
display_step = 100
batch_size = 320

x = tf.placeholder("float", [None, n_input])
y = tf.placeholder("float", [None, n_classes])

predictions = multilayer_perceptron(x, weights, biases, 1)
cost = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits=predictions, labels=y))
optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=1).minimize(cost)
```

This is my code for the tf.session

```
from tensorflow import keras
with tf.Session() as sess:

    # Step 1. Initializing the session
    init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
    writer = tf.summary.FileWriter('/home/dileep/Desktop', sess.graph)

    sess.run(init)

    # Step 2. Dividing x and y to batches
    for epoch in range(training_epochs):
        avg_cost = 0.0
        total_batch = int(len(train_x)//batch_size)
        x_batches = np.array_split(train_x, total_batch)
        y_batches = np.array_split(train_y, total_batch)
        # Step 3. Run session, calculate cost.
        for i in range(total_batch):
            batch_x, batch_y = x_batches[i], y_batches[i]
            _, c = sess.run([optimizer, cost], feed_dict={
                                                    x:batch_x, 
                                                    y:batch_y, keep_prob:0.4})
            avg_cost += c/total_batch
        # Step 4. Print the outputs
        if epoch % display_step == 0:
            print("Epoch:", '%0d' % (epoch+1), "cost=", "{:.9f}".format(avg_cost))
    cost_summary = tf.summary.scalar(name='cost_summary', tensor=avg_cost)
    summary = sess.run(cost_summary)
    writer.add_summary(summary, epoch)
    print("Optimization finished!")

    correct_prediction = tf.equal(tf.argmax(predictions, 1), tf.argmax(y, 1))
    accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_prediction, 'float'))
    print('Accuracy:', accuracy.eval({x: test_x, y: test_y, keep_prob:0.8}))
```

When I run this, the cost function is nicely decreasing with epochs, but the test accuracy is showing as 1. 
I tried substituting test_x and test_y with random numbers and still it is giving an accuracy of 1 so it is obviously wrong. But I am not able to trouble shoot. Could anyone please show me where the problem is? Thank you.

This is the cost graph that I could plot from the above code.
[image]

Comment: Try to decrease the learning rate. `1` is extremely high. A standard value is `0.001`. Also the keep prob is quite high. Try with `0.4`

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot of your loss graph?

Comment: I am a newbie to tensorflow and tensorboard. I used the summary.FileWriter() but am not seeing any loss graph. Could you please tell me what code to add in the above to get the loss graph. Thank you for helping.

Comment: @velociraptor11 I have added the cost/loss graph

Comment: Hmm yeah, that loss curve does not look right. A typical loss curve would be some sort of a curved and plateaus at the end. (I can't attach a picture here since pictures are not allowed in the comments). Leads me to believe that your training isn't working as well as you expected.

Comment: Maybe also post a graph for the training accuracy and test accuracy so we can troubleshoot better

Answer (score 0):

There can be multiple reasons for it, first, let's look at the hyperparameter you are defining.

**Learning rate:**

There are multiple ways to select a good starting point for the learning rate. A naive approach is to try a few different values and see which one gives you the best loss without sacrificing speed of training. We might start with a large value like 0.1, then try exponentially lower values: 0.01, 0.001, etc. When we start training with a large learning rate, the loss doesn’t improve and probably even grows while we run the first few iterations of training. When training with a smaller learning rate, at some point the value of the loss function starts decreasing in the first few iterations. This learning rate is the maximum we can use, any higher value doesn’t let the training converge. Even this value is too high: it won’t be good enough to train for multiple epochs because over time the network will require more fine-grained weight updates. Therefore, a reasonable learning rate to start training from will be probably 1–2 orders of magnitude lower.

**Training data:**

Maybe the number of training data is very less in volume for the model to learn, try including more data by sampling, augmentation techniques.

**Epochs:**

In your code, decrease the `display_step` to 10, so for every 10 steps you will print the loss, if the loss is not changing much for continuous steps, you can bring the epochs number to that range where the loss is not changing. Else if you keep large number of epochs, your model will overfit.

**Test Data:**

Test data should be unseen data from the train instances. Try to give different varients of test data. Including train_test_split to 80/20 % and do data shuffling before splitting train and test data.

I have tried your code on `mnist data` for 10 classes by chaning the above-mentioned parameters and I have got a near benchmark result.

```
from tensorflow.examples.tutorials.mnist import input_data
mnist = input_data.read_data_sets("/tmp/data/", one_hot=True)
train_x=mnist.train.images
train_y = mnist.train.labels
test_x = mnist.test.images
test_y = mnist.test.labels  

def multilayer_perceptron(x, weights, biases, keep_prob):
    layer_1 = tf.add(tf.matmul(x, weights['h1']), biases['b1'])
    layer_1 = tf.nn.relu(layer_1)
    layer_1 = tf.nn.dropout(layer_1, keep_prob)
    out_layer = tf.matmul(layer_1, weights['out']) + biases['out']
    return out_layer

n_hidden_1 = 38
n_input = train_x.shape[1]
n_classes = 10

weights = {
    'h1': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_input, n_hidden_1])),
    'out': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_hidden_1, n_classes]))
}

biases = {
    'b1': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_hidden_1])),
    'out': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_classes]))
}

keep_prob = tf.placeholder("float")

training_epochs = 100
display_step = 10
batch_size = 32

x = tf.placeholder("float", [None, n_input])
y = tf.placeholder("float", [None, n_classes])

predictions = multilayer_perceptron(x, weights, biases, 1)
cost = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits=predictions, labels=y))
optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=0.001).minimize(cost)
```

Train and Test:

```
from tensorflow import keras
with tf.Session() as sess:

    # Step 1. Initializing the session
    init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
    writer = tf.summary.FileWriter('/home/dileep/Desktop', sess.graph)

    sess.run(init)

    # Step 2. Dividing x and y to batches
    for epoch in range(training_epochs):
        avg_cost = 0.0
        total_batch = int(len(train_x)//batch_size)
        x_batches = np.array_split(train_x, total_batch)
        y_batches = np.array_split(train_y, total_batch)
        # Step 3. Run session, calculate cost.
        for i in range(total_batch):
            batch_x, batch_y = x_batches[i], y_batches[i]
            _, c = sess.run([optimizer, cost], feed_dict={
                                                    x:batch_x, 
                                                    y:batch_y, keep_prob:0.4})
            avg_cost += c/total_batch
        # Step 4. Print the outputs
        if epoch % display_step == 0:
            print("Epoch:", '%0d' % (epoch+1), "cost=", "{:.9f}".format(avg_cost))
    cost_summary = tf.summary.scalar(name='cost_summary', tensor=avg_cost)
    summary = sess.run(cost_summary)
    writer.add_summary(summary, epoch)
    print("Optimization finished!")

    correct_prediction = tf.equal(tf.argmax(predictions, 1), tf.argmax(y, 1))
    accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_prediction, 'float'))
    print('Accuracy:', accuracy.eval({x: test_x, y: test_y, keep_prob:0.8}))
```

**Output:**

```
Epoch: 1 cost= 1.206482108
Epoch: 11 cost= 0.040194626
Epoch: 21 cost= 0.025972947
Epoch: 31 cost= 0.019996314
Epoch: 41 cost= 0.016305469
Epoch: 51 cost= 0.013636761
Epoch: 61 cost= 0.011600128
Epoch: 71 cost= 0.009993816
Epoch: 81 cost= 0.008687532
Epoch: 91 cost= 0.007587933
Optimization finished!
Accuracy: 0.9588
```